# django - use locale out of view

Tags: django, localization, django-templates

I am sending emails (in an async way, so no reference to a `request` object), and I'd like the locale to be set to something else that the default. In particular, I'd like to change the decimal separators.

I guess the ideal thing would be that I store in the user model the preferred locale, so that I can use it whenever I want when I perform some action related to that user.

Yet, I don't know how to tell my email template which locale to use.

So 2 questions:

- Where to get the locale of a user (so that I can store it and use it later)?
- More importantly, knowing that I want eg. French locale, how to tell my template to use it to display decimal numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can only change the language and formatting depends on it. In that case, you can do something like this:

```
from django.utils.translation import activate

def my_async_fu(user_id):
    u = User.objects.fet(id=user_id)
    activate(u.my_lang_code_field)
    # Do whatever you want
```